# LIKE expression is not returning expected results. Issue or lack of understanding? (Probably the latter)

Tags: postgresql

Using LIKE '%[0-9]%' to find "yellow 2 x 4 plate".
This is a simplified example that isn't working as I believe it should.

Table (command) with single column (commandtext, varchar).
Single entry in commandtext:  yellow 2 x 4 plate.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM command
WHERE commandtext LIKE '%[0-9]%'
```

Results = Empty set.

I expect that all this should be looking for is a digit between 0-9 surrounded by anythings else.

I am CLEARLY not getting something here...

Comment: Nevermind - SIMILAR TO solved the problem ...

Answer (score 0):

As you have found out, you can use SQL standard `SIMILAR TO`:

```
... WHERE col SIMILAR TO '%[[:digit:]]%'
```

You could also use POSIX regular expressions:

```
... WHERE col ~ '[[:digit:]]'
```